# Checkbox validation with different name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am getting multiple dynamic checkbox with 2 different name one is InProcess and other one is Requested, if user selects check-boxes named InProcess then alert box should be displayed when he selects the checkbox containing the name requested, can anyone guide me how to do that ?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: Please share code in JSFiddle or Stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? I assume more than one set and I also assume the container is static

```js
$(".container").on("change", "[type=checkbox]", function() {
  if ($(this).is("[name=Requested]") &&
    $(this).siblings("[name=InProcess]").is(":checked")) {
    alert("In progress")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="InProcess" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Requested" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="InProcess" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Requested" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```js
$(document).on("change", "input[name='Requested']", function() {
  if ($("input[name='InProcess']").prop("checked") == true && $(this).prop("checked") == true) {
    alert("InProcess is checked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="InProcess"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Requested"/>
```

Comment: This will not work. The checkboxes are dynamic. You need to delegate